# Arduino Serial Tx and Rx message

Tags: arduino, esp32

I am using Arduino with M5 Stamp (https://shop.m5stack.com/products/m5stamp-pico-5pcs) and trying to implement a serial interface to tx and rx message  . The Tx message is like `0x55 0xCD 0x47 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x69 0x0D 0x0A` and the Rx message is like `0xAA 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0xDA 0x00 0x00 0x03 0x32 0x08 0x8E 0x18 0xF6 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x2A 0x00 0x0C 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x47 0x03 0xE3 0x0D 0x0A` and always is 40 HEX.

I manage to come up with a nasty solution of counting 40 HEX with array and print the message out.

```
void receivemsgloop(void *pvParam)
{
  Serial.println("receivemsgloop start");
  int incomingByte = 0;
  unsigned char msg[40];
  int i = 0;
  while (1)
  {
    if (Serial2.available() > 0)
    {
      // read the incoming byte:
      incomingByte = Serial2.read();
      // counting the incomingByte and store in the array??
      if (i < 40)
      {
        msg[i] = incomingByte;
        i++;
      }
      else
      { //else array full and print out
        Serial.print("s2 received msg: ");
        for(int c=0;c<40;c++){
        Serial.println(msg[c],HEX);}
        Serial.println();
        i=0;
      }
    }
  }
  Serial.println("receivemsgloop end");
}
```

Is there have anyway store the HEX array without using the array loop? I have try the Serial.readSting() but not really working. Thanks.

Comment: You know you don’t have to send the data in hex, right? You can just transmit and receive the individual bytes.

Comment: Do you mean using byte instead of Hex? and the rx msg become string?

Comment: I found that the loop also have problem.  s2 received: AA
s2 received msg: AA000032003137C61B94010001E0A040000000000472B5DA.  s2 received: AA
s2 received: 0
s2 received msg: 000032003117D01B8001000C040200000000004728FDAAA

Comment: it is shifting one char every time.....

Comment: The shifting issue is because you're checking whether the array is full after you've read a byte - so the 1st byte of the next message is being thrown away. You need to read the byte - add it to the array, and then check `if (i == 40)` and print out the array.  readString won't work - because it's binary data - there are null characters in the middle that will terminate the string. Do you have control over the format of the messages being sent and received?

Comment: Nop, I dont have control over how the message send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated the function and added a if cause for checking the ending sequence if the ending sequence is not0x0D 0x0A discard it. Tested for one night and seem ok.

```
void receivemsgloop(void *pvParam)
{
  Serial.println("receivemsgloop start");
  int incomingByte = 0;
  uint8_t msg[40];
  static String msg_out="";
  char *msg_out_1;
  int i = 0;

  while (1)
  {
    if (Serial2.available() > 0)
    {
      while (i < 40)
      { // read the incoming byte:
        if (Serial2.available())
        {
          incomingByte = Serial2.read();
          msg[i] = incomingByte;
          i++;
        }
      }

      Serial.print("s2 received msg: ");
      if (msg[38] == 0x0D && msg[39] == 0x0A)
      {
        for (int c = 0; c < 40; c++)
        {
          Serial.print(msg[c], HEX);
          msg_out += msg[c];
        }
      }

      Serial.println();
      Serial.println(msg_out);
      msg_out = "";
      i = 0;
    }

  }
  Serial.println("receivemsgloop end");
}
```